# How do I make sure my static library has the right architectures for CocoaLibSpotify?

Tags: swift, libspotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I get this error when I try to build a project using CocoaLibSpotify.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FLibrary/libspotify-12.1.64-iOS-universal'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/tgm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CocoaLibSpotify_iOS_Library-gtxluzeubophcpfplfiyijlecxzt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLibSpotify.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/tgm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CocoaLibSpotify_iOS_Library-gtxluzeubophcpfplfiyijlecxzt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLibSpotify.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SPSession", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo9SPSession in DetailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I used `lipo` to check the architectures in the referenced static library:

```
$ lipo -info /Users/tgm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CocoaLibSpotify_iOS_Library-gtxluzeubophcpfplfiyijlecxzt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLibSpotify.a
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/tgm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CocoaLibSpotify_iOS_Library-gtxluzeubophcpfplfiyijlecxzt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaLibSpotify.a are: armv7 arm64
```

isn't `arm64` the right label for `x86_64`?

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaLibSpotify doesn't support `arm64` (64-bit device) or `x86_64` (64-bit Simulator) for iOS. To build an app with CocoaLibSpotify, you can only target `armv6`, `armv7` or `armv7s`.

For a more modern library, might I suggest the new [Spotify iOS SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/)?

Comment: are you or your colleagues maintaining a list of capabilities of each version (at least the latest version) of the sdk?